# Using Local Database w/ JQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, android, database, local-storage

I'm writing a web application with using JQuery. My application will mostly work on Android. I want to have a local database at the client's side so that my web application can store data at client's browser and work even when the internet connection's broken. I'm seeing that there are so many options such as plug-in, jStorage, HTML5 WebStorage, ixedit and many more; however, I'd want to get the opinions from the people who have knowledge and experience.

What solution would you suggest?

Thank you!

p.s. If I can be able to use SQL on local db, it'd be nicer.

Comment: Sounds like this previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410987/html5-offline-storage-with-android-browsers might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Look to : [localStorageDB](http://kailashnadh.name/code/localstoragedb/) plugin

`localStorageDB is a simple layer over localStorage that provides a set of functions to store structured data like databases and tables. It provides basic insert/update/delete/query capabilities. localStorageDB has no dependencies, and is not based on WebSQL. Underneath it all, the structured data is stored as serialized JSON in localStorage.` 
Data creating, manipulating, deleing, Querying etc. are very easy and its coding is pure JQuery.

Edit: if you prefer an SQL based solution, you can try **HTML 5 Web SQL Database** from [here](http://openbit.co.uk/?p=135)